# How can I add someone to a meeting from a certain date?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook

I have set up a recurring meeting with several people. I need to add an individual from a certain date onwards. How can I do this?

I have also been asked to send an invite to another individual who will attend alternate weeks - is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to add an individual from a certain date onwards.

To add new participants to an existed Outlook meeting, you could directly double click to add the new participants and updates the meeting.

However, as I know, the meeting time is one of the basic attribute, it will not change along with the change of participants and also we could not custom a specific time range for specific participants.

Outlook provides us options to change this entire series or only this meeting. You can add the new participants to based on these options when you need. And if specific participant is no longer need to attend this recurring meeting, the participant himself can cancel this recurring meeting on his own side. Meeting organizer can also remove these participants if necessary.

[Change an appointment, meeting, or event](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-an-appointment-meeting-or-event-29b44f7a-8938-4b99-b98d-3efcf45f7613)

Comment: Have you got your issue fixed? If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Thanks.